# I have written same html code to display 2 horizontal line but I'm getting 2 horizontal line with different thikness

Tags: html, css, web, tags

I wanted to display 2 horizontal lines.
I used the same code i.e.,

```
<hr size:"2" color:"black">
```

in order to make the two lines, but I'm getting 2 lines with different thickness.

I'm using VS Code in my Windows 10 OS.

Comment: Share your code here or codepen etc, so can get your issue.

Comment: Please have a look at this before asking: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problems before and I noticed it's because of the way the browser renders the lines. If you zoom-in you'll *probably* see they have the same thickness.